# PHP Explode - Remove first part of string, then last part

Tags: php, explode

I'm creating a simple database restore script, but I ran into a bump in the road.

Database dump files are created with the script as well, and have the following filename format: datestamp-dbname.sql

With the restore script, I need to remove the datestamp, the hyphen and the .sql, to just leave the dbname.

I currently have this, which removes the first part, but I need to remove the .sql as well.

```
$getfilename = $_GET['filename'];
$dbname = explode("-", $getfilename[2]);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list ($timestamp, $dbname) = explode('-', basename($filename, '.sql'));
```

[`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) (with optional second argument) removes the file extension. The rest is trivial.

Another solution:

```
$dbname = substr($filename, strpos($filename, '-') + 1, -4);
```

Just take the string between `-` (excluding: `+1`) and 4 characters before the end of the string.

I would prefer the first solution, because it feels a little bit cleaner to me (and even more readable)

Answer (score 0):

The first element of an array has the index zero, not one. You want:

```
$tmp = explode('-', $getfilename);
$dbname = $tmp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$getfilename = $_GET['filename'];
$dbname = explode("-", $getfilename);
$dbname[1] // this is what you need
```